# The site specified an invalid Strict-Transport-Security header - firebug

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers, firebug

I am getting this warning in firebug when adding HSTS header.

```
The site specified an invalid Strict-Transport-Security header.
```

here is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
    Header append Strict-Transport-Security: 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
</IfModule>
```

When I remove quotes from the value I get `Internal Server Error`.
Website is being served through https, redirect from http to https is set from apache's site file. SSL certificate is self-signed, if it matters.

mod headers is enabled. Im on debian 7, apache 2.2.

Thanks

Comment: What if you follow https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security with: `Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"`?

Comment: @jhutar, tks for the comment, just tried it, same thing...

Comment: OK, just solved it in my case. I have seen that error in Firefox's console when accessing some development server with self-signed certificate. When I have imported server's CA cert and removed exception I have added before for that server, error disappeared.

Comment: @jhutar, yeah im in dev with self-signed cert, will check it when moving into production with real cert, thanks for the information

Comment: or you can just import CA cert used to sign your httpd cert as I did. Worked for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @jhutar mentioned in comments, similarly in my case as I set up the site on the main domain with trusted SSL certificate the problem disappeared. So, the firebug is showing that error only for self-signed(and/or not-trusted) SSL certificates.