# Spring HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) And FireFox

Tags: spring, security, firefox, spring-security, hsts

The spring security (4.0.1.Release) set the HSTS host by default for https protocol and you can see `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ;` in the response header (I used Firefox>Web Development>Network  ).

But when I look at firefox console I see an error which says: `The site specified an invalid Strict-Transport-Security header.` 
I also set the hsts header manually in spring config as :

```
    <headers>
        <hsts />
    </headers>
```

The same response header is generated and the FireFox show error again.

According to the https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security the header must be correct !

Any comments ?!

[image]

Comment: Does this happen when you access the website over plain HTTP, or is it when accessed over HTTPS?

Comment: When access to HTTPS

Comment: How do other browsers handle the header? Please could you add a screenshot of the browser showing the response headers and the error?

Comment: I have add a pic which shows the header request header and firefox error

Comment: The only things that springs to mind are the space after the number of seconds, or the face that you are running on a non standard HTTPS port (8443 instead of 443). [HSTS](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=613645) may not know what to do if you are not running on the usual 80/443 pair.

Comment: For port you are right, but it did not solve the issue, So you as you said **max-age=31536000 ;** should be replace with **max-age=31536000;**, I will check it !

Comment: What does clicking Learn More give you?

Comment: This url: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Comment: Removing the space also did not solve this error log!

Answer (score 1):

I found it was a bug in firefox as mentioned in [The site specified an invalid Strict-Transport-Security header - firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367305/the-site-specified-an-invalid-strict-transport-security-header-firebug).

The self-signed certificate seems to generate this issue.

Also refer to: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-3021

Answer (score 1):

Try this, so I solved a similar problem:

You could enter **about:config** into the firefox address bar (confirm the info message in case it shows up) and search for the preference named **security.enterprise_roots.enabled** double-click it and change its value to **true** and restart firefox.

[image: config firefox]